# How to use jquery to get full filepath when uploading a file?

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I am having a bit of an issue getting the file path from the browser and was hoping that someone could help me out. I do know that in FF3 and Chrome that the file path isn't available as a "security feature". Unfortunately for me I am trying to upload files to the Rackspace Cloud using PHP on the back end and it requires the full filename. I'd like to be able to do this with AJAX instead of submitting the form but haven't been able to find anything. Does anyone know a work around to get this data?

Comment: it requires the full filename? Change you PHP code not to.

Comment: a while back I asked the same question, you cannot get the file path. If your third party needs the file path you need to point them at the file upload control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know a work around to get this data?

There is none. I don't think even Flash based uploaders do this any more. The original location is none of the receiving site's business any more - that is the new rule; you need to change your programs accordingly.

> I'd like to be able to do this with AJAX instead of submitting the form

That wouldn't be possible even if you *had* the full file name - you will not get read access to a local file (barring some new HTML 5 shenanigans that aren't widely supported yet.)